# Linked Server using Impersonation fails SSMS GUI Connection test but sp_testlinkedserver succeeds

Tags: sql-server-2014, permissions, linked-server

I have a linked server (Server B) set up on Server A with permissions set as follows:

[image]

This means that there are five Windows Logins (of which my windows account is one) who can access the linked server on Server A and the permissions they will have when using the linked server are the permissions they have set on Server B.

If I log into SSMS as myself on my local machine (which isn't the server), connect the object explorer to Server A, right click on the Server B linked server and select "Test connection" I get the following error:

[image]

However, when I run the following code on Server A, the command completes successfully:

```
DECLARE @name SYSNAME = 'ServerB'
EXEC sp_testlinkedserver @servername  = @name
```

I can also verify that the linked server works by querying it as below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [ServerB].[MyDb].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

which returns `1` as expected.

Why does the connection test in the GUI fail when clearly everything is working as it should be?

Comment: "However, when I run the following code on Server A, the command completes successfully:". Are you still running the query with SSMS from your machine or are you connected to the Server A VM when running the query? The guid should still be executing `EXEC sp_testlinkedserver N'Servername'` when testing the connection

Comment: I am running the query in the same instance of management studio, on my local machine

Comment: What is returned when you run this: `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid`

Comment: select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid returns KERBEROS On both ServerA and ServerB

Comment: Is the service account on ServerA set as trust this user for delegation to any service?

Comment: select auth_scheme, * from sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE client_net_address = 'MyPCIP' returns all connections showing KERBEROS, suggesting the Object explorer session is also running Kerberos

Comment: It could be that your spns are set but the service account is not trusted for delegation. You could check that with the [kerberos configuration manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046). On my end without delegation the connection can still use kerberos (but not delegate tickets)

Comment: The service account is NT Service\MSSQLSERVER and the AD computer account for Server A (and Server B) is set to "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" I'll check the kerberos config manager after lunch